# Is there any method of importing .css files conditionally in React.JS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to add a dark-mode in my project. Without React, I would have just targetted the DOM element which triggers the switching of the mode and linked my custom dark.css file instead of index.css which happens to be my pre-dominant  CSS file. But here in React, it would take the latest file I'm importing for my CSS. I'm a beginner in React. So please pardon me if this doesn't make much sense. Thanks in advance!
Here's my code

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
{/*import './dark.css*/}

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way. You can use `React.Lazy` and `React.Suspense`.

For example [this article](https://medium.com/@prawira/react-conditional-import-conditional-css-import-110cc58e0da6) explains how use them.

Comment: [Here](https://medium.com/swlh/setting-up-light-and-dark-mode-in-a-react-application-just-with-styles-7790dea22aed) is maybe easier way.

Comment: Medium is asking me to upgrade to read the article, we shouldn't link there

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with importing `dark.css` every time, but its styles should be *applied* conditionally. What I mean is, all the styles for dark mode should be wrapped in a CSS class like `.dark-mode`. Then, when user turns dark mode on, you would apply this class to `body` tag or to the top-level React component, and remove it when dark mode is turned off.

This will be a much easier solution that trying to work with lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone viewing this, I would strongly recommend using useContext. It makes it very easy to pass your theme without using props to all of your children. They even have an example of implementing dark/light theme like you want: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useContext#usage

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33586789)